# jQuery function that dynamically load data AND also execute js?

Tags: javascript, jquery

For example we have two php pages (same domain):

- index.php
- data.php (that uses a jQuery script)

If I load a part of the "data.php" inside the "index.php" I have to re execute the js file from the "data.php" like this:

```
$( ".box" ).load("data.php .my_data", function() {
  $.getScript("https://website.com/js/data.js");
});
```

Is there an other/better way to load a part from the external data.php and automatically execute all js that is connected with it?

Answer (score 0):

`data.php` (this template contains no script)

```
<div class="template">
    <div class="title">
        <span>Title</span>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
        <span>Content</span>
    </div>
    <div>
        <button type="button">Read</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Script on `index.php`:

In this example, I just show the event when clicking on the button, there are some ways to define it:

Option 1: Write the event after loading template successfully

```
$('.box').load('data.php').done(function (template) {
    template = $(template).appendTo('body');

    template.on('click', 'button', function () {
        console.log('clicked!');
    });
});
```

Option 2: Write the event outside the event which is used to load the template

```
$('.box').load('data.php').done(function (template) {
    $(template).appendTo('body');
});

$(document).on('click', 'button', function () {
    console.log('clicked!');
});
```

This ways require all of the scripts which are working on `data.php` are ready on `index.php`.

If you don't want to move/split the code:

`data.php`:

```
<div class="template">
    <div class="title">
        <span>Title</span>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
        <span>Content</span>
    </div>
    <div>
        <button type="button">Read</button>
    </div>
</div>
<script src="/js/data.js"></script>
```

In the file `data.js`, if you want to load something more but not immediately, make sure you're working with `document` (there are more ways but I highly recommend this):

`data.js`

```
// this code works imediately after your document has `.load` class
$(document).on('click', '.load', function () {
    // this code will work if your document already has `.box` class
    $('.box').load('some_data.php').done(function (template) {
        console.log(template);
    });
});
```

On the `index.php`, after appending the template, the code will work correctly. Nothing is *automatically* more.